# Is there some trick to writing code snippets?

Tags: feature-request, support

It seems, from the reference linked to my right as I type, that to put in code snippets I need to indent everything at least four spaces.  Is there some easy way to do this automatically for a large block?  I imagine that SO would have solved this since that's a site about coding, but I can't see how it's done.

(MarkdownExtra solves this by allowing "fenced" code blocks: pre- and append the block with a line consisting of three (or more) tildes.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can select the text you want to convert to a code snippet and press the **Code Sample button** in the bar above the text area (or, alternatively, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>). Is that what you want or am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps it's a mark of how much of a commandline junkie I am that I automatically blank that out from my field of vision!  That's _exactly_ what I want.  Thanks.

Comment: Just for others: On Mac OSX it’s `cmd`+`K`

Answer (score 5):

For TeX code please use the code sample button (now looks like `{}`; shortcut CTRL+K). For non-TeX we previously suggested to use manual `<pre> .. </pre>` HTML tags. However a better solution is to use the code sample button as well but add a HTML comment before it to specify the language for the syntax highlighting.

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->

    some code without syntax highlighting
    note the HTML comment and the single separation line beforehand
```

Relevant languages for TeX.SX are `lang-tex` (default), `lang-none` (disable syntax highlighting), `lang-sh` (shell code/scripts) and `lang-perl` (Perl code/scripts).
For a list of all languages see: 
[Manually specify language for syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971)

Answer (score 2):

Besides using that 101010 button on the toolbar, you could just use `<pre>`.

```
Like
    this.
```

But using `<pre>` there will be no code highlighting.

Comment: and in `<pre>` you have to manually escape &gt; and &lt; too

Comment: and the "101010" button now is a "{ }" button. (As of right now, only on the main site, not on meta yet.)